# :css3-container XPath Selector

Tags: c#, javascript, html, xpath

I have the following line of code in an html file, I have no idea what is is and why there is a : infront. However, I am processing the DOM and want to remove all similar nodes using an xpath selector. I can't seem to be able to use "//:css-container" to select the element.

```
<:css3-container style="z-index: 3000; position: absolute; direction: ltr; top: 92px; left: -9998px;">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And these elements are present in the dom or are they just text?

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the DOM you could try

```
//*[local-name() = "css3-container"]
```

or

```
//*[local-name() = ":css3-container"]
```

(if it not considered an empty namespace)